# Use member function of another class without object and avoid static

Tags: c++, class, c++11

This question is different from those duplicated ones.

I have 2 classes A and B. B has a member function `B::boy` that uses its variable `b`.

A has a member function `A::evaluate` and in this member function, I need to use `B::boy`.

The problem now is that :

1) `B::boy` cannot be static because it needs to use a non-static variable `b`.

2) I cannot instantiate a object of B in A. Because I have one object of B elsewhere and that stores the variable `b` that is also useful in A.

Is it not possible to be done in C++?

Comment: How about passing a reference to the `B` object when constructing the `A` object, and then store that reference for future use? Or use [shared pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of your current instance and references (to ensure lifetime of the object)? Or just pass the `B` object (possibly as a reference) to the function in `A`?

Comment: You have multiple ways of making `B::boy` available to `A::evaluate`. It all depends on where's your non-static variable `b` declared.

Comment: To fully answer your question, we need some code

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I declared b when creating the first object of B in the construction function. Then I changed value of b some places elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `b` as a parameter of `A::evaluate` or have pointer or reference member of B in A (depends on how "useful" that `b` value in your `A` class).